# Javascript countdown that persists across page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, countdowntimer, persistent

I am trying to make a countdown, which do not restart after refreshing this page. I am using keith wood countdown. I want to count to 5 minutes.

```
var countdownTarget = localStorage.getItem('countdownTarget');
    if (countdownTarget === null) 
    {
        var countdownTarget = new Date();
        countdownTarget = new Date(countdownTarget.getFullYear(), countdownTarget.getMonth(), countdownTarget.getDate(), countdownTarget.getHours(), countdownTarget.getMinutes() + 5, countdownTarget.getSeconds());
        localStorage.setItem('countdownTarget', countdownTarget);
    }

    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until : countdownTarget, format: 'MS', compact: true});
```

I am saving the current date + 5 minutes to browser local storage as  countdownTarget (only if it was not done before). And if an user refresh the page, the time should be persistent. But there is problem. When I load the page for the first time, the time is counting from 5 minutes (that should be normal), but when I am trying to refresh it again it starts counting from 36 minutes and I do not know why and I do not know where these 36 minutes came from.

Comment: Where do the 36 minutes come from? Can't see anything like this in your code example.

Comment: you probably don't mean to shadow countdownTarget if null by saying var =

Comment: I am pretty sure that localStorage stores data as strings. If you are loading the stored string from localStorage and then adding it to an int, you are not going to get the expected result. You need to convert that stored string back to an int before adding it to your counter.

Comment: @Korgrue Thank you! You were right. Now I solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-declaring the date, why not just increment the minutes? Your code worked for me. Also, you should only initiate `countdownTarget` once.

```
var countdownTarget = localStorage.getItem('countdownTarget');
if (countdownTarget === null) {
    countdownTarget = new Date();
    countdownTarget.setMinutes(countdownTarget.getMinutes() + 5);
    localStorage.setItem('countdownTarget', countdownTarget);
} else {
    countdownTarget = new Date(countdownTarget);
}
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until : countdownTarget, format: 'MS', compact: true});
```